# Website posted on GitHub not formatting my CSS

Tags: css

I have placed my CSS and Images folders and index.html on GitHub. Only the html displays without the CSS formatting.  I have cleared my cache and cookies.  I'm using Chrome. I can't seem to get the CSS formatting to work.

Can anyone help?

uploaded web files to Github:  https://github.com/Dennybribri/cv

I have attached a picture of how the top part of the website should look like.  Here is a link to the site from Github that just displays the html: https://dennybribri.github.io/cv/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Mahmoud and Merlin.  I changed the folder names to lower case and forever have this issue stuck in my brain.  It works great!

Comment: Hi @Dennybribri if  any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. The answering feature though is not meant for this.

Answer (score 0):

Rename your folder from `CSS` to `css`.

Answer (score 0):

The filesystem used on the servers of Github pages sites is case sensitive.
You'll need to import your css from the `CSS` folder:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/styles.css">
```

Also because of the same problem your images will not show up. You will need to specify the path to `Images/someimage.jpg` instead of `images/someimage.jpg`